# how to avoid maps tag mapping to hyperlink and calling an onclick function instaed html php js

Tags: javascript, php, html, hyperlink, area

I am trying to make a 4-buttoned image to work as 4 buttons mapped to 4 different functions instead of default hyperlinks (href=#).
What I wish is that the user data is added edited deleted or updated within this PHP page instead of explicit hyperlinks to different pages.
Even if I have to resort to other pages, this data needs to be submitted via functions of the post or get etc or some own function. But the issue is that after mapping this image as 4 different buttons and even removing the href and adding onclick=myfunction(), it does nothing and if I add href, it doesn't go to myfunction after clicking and takes to href link instead.
please help.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Panel
    </title>
    <?php
    require('connect.php');   //working connection
    $queryU = "SELECT username FROM `user`";
    $listU  = $connection->query($queryU);
    if ($listU->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($rowu = $listU->fetch_assoc()) {
            $y = $rowu['username'];    //working script
        }
    }
    ?>
    <style>
        body {
            background-image : url("main.jpg");
            opacity          : 40%;
            font-family      : AlphaMaleModern;
            text-align       : center;
            color            : #fff;
            font-size        : 26px;
        }    
        .a {
            height : 90%;  width  : 45%;
        }

        .img {
            margin-top : 20%;
            position   : relative;
        }    
        .list {
            float    : right;
            position : absolute;
            border   : lime solid;
            width    : 50%;
            z-index  : -1;
            position : static;
            top      : 10%;
            height   : 90%;
        }    
        #userlist {
            width       : 100%;
            opacity     : 0.8;
            font-family : AlphaMaleModern;
            text-align  : center;
            font-size   : 28px;
            height      : 100%;
        }    
        .img:hover, #userlist:hover {
            opacity : 1;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        //test function 1 for on click call but not working
        document.getElementById('aa').on(click, function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                alert("CLICKED");
            }
        );
        //test function 2 for on click call but not working
        function printr(ss) {
            var x = document.getElementById('ss').name;
            alert(x);
            switch (x) {
                case "aa":
                    alert("AA");
                    break;
                case "b":
                    alert("B");
                    break;
                case "c":
                    alert("C");
                    break;
                case "d":
                    alert("D");
                    break;
            }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<fieldset name="Users" class="a" style="float:right;">
    <legend>USERS
    </legend>
    <div id="user" class="user" style="">
        <img src="panel/panel.png" class="img" alt="" usemap="#Map1"/>
        <map name="Map1" id="Map1">
            <area alt="" title="" href="#" id="aa" onclick="printr(aa)" 
                  shape="poly" coords="200,8,16,10,104,108"/>
            <area alt="" title="" href="#" id="b" onclick="printr(b)" 
                  shape="poly" coords="205,14,108,109,204,197"/>
            <area alt="" title="" href="#" id="c" onclick="printr(c)" 
                  shape="poly" coords="8,201,98,110,8,15"/>
            <area alt="" title="" href="#" id="d" onclick="printr(d)" 
                  shape="poly" coords="104,113,16,208,204,207"/>
        </map>
        <div class="list">
            <select id="userlist" size="20">
                <option>
                    <?php echo $y; ?>
                </option>
                <!--list of users from mysql database (working good)-->
            </select>
        </div>
</fieldset>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

image:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I'll answer in few steps.
   Firstly – your html block comment in 98 line is wrong.
   It is:

`<!--list of users from mysql database (working good) --!>`

but is should looks like that:

`<!--list of users from mysql database (working good) -->`

Because of that wrong comment closing (which isn't close) – every line under that comment was commented too.

2. Your `function printr(ss)` isn't closed. Last `}` is closing of `switch`.
3. You've `onclick="printr(aa)"` instead of `onclick="printr('aa')"`. Without `'` brackets you're giving function argument nonexistent variable `aa`. With brackets you're giving just string.

---

My version of code:

```
  <html>
  <head>
    <title>Panel
    </title>

    <style>
      body{
        background-image: url("main.jpg");
        opacity:40%;
        font-family: AlphaMaleModern;
        text-align:center;
        color:#fff;
        font-size: 26px;
      }
      .a{
        height:90%;
        width:45%;
      }
      .img{
        margin-top:20%;
        position:relative;
      }
      .list{
        float:right;
        position:absolute;
        border:lime solid;
        width:50%;
        z-index:-1;
        position:static;
        top:10%;
        height:90%;
      }
      #userlist{
        width:100%;
        opacity: 0.8;
        font-family:AlphaMaleModern;
        text-align:center;
        font-size:28px;
        height:100%;
      }
      .img:hover,#userlist:hover{
        opacity: 1;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
        function printr(ss)
        {
            switch (ss)
            {
                case "aa":
                alert("AA");
                break;
                case "b":
                alert("B");
                break;
                case "c":
                alert("C");
                break;
                case "d":
                alert("D");
                break;
            }
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <fieldset name="Users" class="a" style="float:right;">
      <legend>USERS
      </legend>
      <div id="user" class="user"  style="">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7A0Ky.png" class="img" alt="" usemap="#Map1" />
        <map name="Map1" id="Map1">
          <area alt="" title="" href="#" id="aa" onclick="printr('aa')" shape="poly" coords="200,8,16,10,104,108" />
          <area alt="" title="" href="#" id="b" onclick="printr('b')" shape="poly" coords="205,14,108,109,204,197" />
          <area alt="" title="" href="#" id="c" onclick="printr('c')" shape="poly" coords="8,201,98,110,8,15" />
          <area alt="" title="" href="#" id="d" onclick="printr('d')" shape="poly" coords="104,113,16,208,204,207" />
        </map>
        <div class="list"  >
          <select id="userlist" size="20">
            <option>

            </option>   
            <!--list of users from mysql database (working good) -->
</select>
</div>
</fieldset>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9ks9kxzw/

That's not as clear code as it could be, but it's working now.
By the way – I've removed php sections etc. to not disturb myself. I hope you understand what have I done. Remember that if you have error in javascript – it'll just don't execute.

Comment: i really appreciate your effort to sort out the errors  but even after error-removal, the main question remains the same. as i tested a simple alert () call in JS in the start of script which works but the onclick() on any of the image mapping never worked. please help!!

Comment: It's possible that I've don't enumerate one or two bugs. Have you checked if everything's working at jsfiddle (link near the end of answer)? For me it is working for every browser have.

Comment: the only issue left is that you have removed couple of lines from the code which were actually hindering it from running. These are:

Comment: function printr(ss){
 var x = document.getElementById("ss").name;
        alert('x');

Comment: I've deleted some of javascript code to keep it simple. It's possible there was a bug that I haven't notice.

Comment: Code under first comment ("function 1", as you call it) wasn't necessary – I decided to use second way to solve it ("function 2"). In that function (named ``printr``) you don't need ``var x = document.getElementById('ss').name;`` to have the rest working. In html you have triggers (``onclick="printf("string")`` and that's all you need to identify which one was clicked.

Comment: Everything's identifying though ``switch``. If you want any improvements – please, tell me. I haven't any presumption to think that's nesesery for more than just tests ;)

Comment: Yes i need help . the aim is to call php functions through these buttons because php can't be called directly except via get or post methods.but get and post cant be associated to these buttons i suppose. the objective is to connect to a mysql server whose code has been incorporated via PHP.but how to trigger a php function which will simple click on these buttons in order to send specific html object (username is this case) to that php script . As far as i know, the only method which sends the data to php is get or post that too, using submit buttons perhaps.i am wondering how to...

Comment: Can i use post or get methods invoked by "onclick"? i.e.   

    <area alt="" title="" href="#" id="aa" onclick="user.php" 
    method="POST" shape="poly" 
    coords="200,8,16,10,104,108" />
@Sylogista i hope you might understand what i am trying to do.. i am trying to send the selected user in the listbox to the php to delete or edit his data. i also wish to update his info via update button leading to a little form opened by a click on update/edit button so that his info is changed.

Comment: i have successfully submitted user-details by wrapping the map by form tag. and attaching formname.submit() button onClick of delete button. but now issue remaining is of viewing button and others as those are supposed to submit form to some other script of php instead of delete script. @Sylogista please help